# java onCreate showing errors for new layout

Tags: android-activity

I've used onCreate to start activities but for some reason the code is showing errors in this instance.

`@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.moulding);
    }`

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object    Moulding.java   /GradeTools/src/com/sntnmjones/gradetools   line 17 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type Moulding must override or implement a supertype method  Moulding.java   /GradeTools/src/com/sntnmjones/gradetools   line 16 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type Moulding   Moulding.java   /GradeTools/src/com/sntnmjones/gradetools   line 18 Java Problem

I'm using this exact code to launch new activities elsewhere though, so why is it not working here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So at the top of Moulding.java after the import.android.os.Bundle I had to put 
`public class Moulding extends gradesButton {`